# bluestacks get some error occured

Tags: bluestacks

So I installed bluestacks and playing some games, but after 1 week it started to get some errors mid game that I can't copy or screen shot cause it close right after the error.

I uninstalled bluestacks then I installed bluestacks again but now when I open bluestacks it get the error: Some error occurred.

Reinstalled it many times, clean uninstall using revo uninstaller then restart then got new installer and it still get some error occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw the fix in a youtube video. https://youtu.be/NN6K19PhmkQ

Ctrl+Alt+Delete, open Task Manager, then go to Services. From there, scroll through the list and find "BstHdAndroidSvc."

Right click it and click Start. Afterwards, Bluestacks shouldn't give error upon opening. This is just a workaround. Unfortunately, you have to do this every time you want to open Bluestacks.